# scala breeze multiply matrix by transpose

Tags: matrix, breeze, multiplication

I want to multiply two matrices. A * B works just fine. But what I really want is A.t * B. But after transposing A, the result becomes Transpose[Matrix[Double]] instead of Matrix[Double]. As a result the operation is rejected by the compiler. However, mathematically, the transpose of a matrix is another matrix, and it should be perfectly ok to multiply that by another matrix. How is this properly done in breeze?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I was using a plain Matrix type in Breeze, for example something like this:

```
def buildMatrix(): Matrix[Double] = {
  DenseMatrix((1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0))
}

val m = buildMatrix()
val t = m.t
m * t
```

gives me the compiler error `Error:(13, 69) could not find implicit value for parameter op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpMulMatrix.Impl2[breeze.linalg.Matrix[Double],breeze.linalg.Transpose[breeze.linalg.Matrix[Double]],That]`

But if I make sure that the matrix I'm transposing is a DenseMatrix, like this:

```
val m = buildMatrix().toDenseMatrix
```

Then the `*` operator works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A.t.asInstanceOf[DenseMatrix[Double]] did the trick.

Comment: If `A` has type `DenseMatrix[Double]` then `A.t` should also be a `DenseMatrix[Double]`. So if you know that `A` has run time type `DenseMatrix[Double]` (which you apparently do), then you can just make `A` have compile time type `DenseMatix[Double]`. This will enable you to do `A.t*B` without the cast.

Comment: A already has type DenseMatrix[Double]. Still I had this problem before casting.

Comment: Does it have *compile-time* type `DenseMatrix[Double]`? I tried `A.t` (where `A` has compile-time type `DenseMatrix[Double]`) and the result was another `DenseMatrix[Double]`, while, if `A` has compile-time type `Matrix[Double]`, then `A.t` results in a `Tranpose[Matrix[Double]]`.